# Need a Logic to solve the task

Tags: sql, oracle

How to skip the null values

Example Table Structure: Table Name : T1

**ID A_Comments A_ts B_Comments B_ts C_Comments C_ts** 

1  Approved   20   Simple     null  fine      null 

1  Approved null   Simple      10   fine      null

1  Approved  null  Simple     null  fine       30

Expecting result:

**ID A_Comments A_ts B_Comments B_ts C_Comments C_ts**

1  Approved   20   Simple     10    fine      30

Comment: Your column wise sample data is not readable :(

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
select id, max(a_comments) as a_commments, max(a_ts) as a_ts, . . .
from t1
group by id;
```

I am guessing that your table was created by an aggregation query with one too many columns in the `group by`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Gordon Linoff. I will try it tomorrow and let you know.